# Laravel hasRole() error while creating user management

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.4

- I am new to laravel5.4. By using [this url](https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission) i am trying to make user management. After installing everything i got below error. Please help this out to fix this error

---

```
(3/3) ErrorException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRole() (View: /var/www/html/laravel5/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/laravel5/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

- My layout app.blade.php is as below

---

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        @role('Admin') {{-- Laravel-permission blade helper --}}
                                            <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-unlock"></i>Admin</a>
                                        @endrole
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
</ul>
```

Comment: did you add `use HasRoles;` on User model?

Comment: post your controller method too